# What's the difference between Android TensorFlow support and TensorFlow Lite for Android？

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I see a sample in Google codelabs [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-style-transfer-android/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

it requirements dependencies Android TensorFlow support

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.2.0-preview'
}
```

I know the TensorFlow Lite was help developer to use the model in mobile 
devices

What's the difference between these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet which you provided corresponds to TensorFlow Mobile.

- TensorFlow Mobile is a program useful for running protocol buffers ( .pb ) files on Android , iOS and other IoT stuff. It can only be used to run inferences on a TensorFlow model which is converted to a .pb file. It can only function over specific platforms.
- [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) is a successor of TensorFlow Mobile. Lite can run inferences on models which are converted to a .tflite file. The Lite version also allows the developer to run Graphs, Sessions and Tensors over Java and Android. It also provides the Neural Networks API. It can functions over Android and iOS devices, [Firebase MLKit](https://firebase.google.com/mlkit), [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) and also TensorFlow C++ APIs.

Even Google recommends to use TensorFlow Lite instead of TensorFlow Mobile.